# How to check if a postgresql backup is finished or not?

Tags: postgresql, backup

I started my backup yesterday, but now I don't know if it is finished or not.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the function `pg_is_in_backup()` in PostgreSQL >= 9.3, see [Backup Control Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-BACKUP)

For example:

```
SELECT pg_is_in_backup();
```

If the result is false, then the computer is not currently backing up. But this depends on the kind of backup you're doing (i.e. via PgAdminIII, SQL command, or pgdump).

Comment: I tried that, but it gives an error:  ERROR:  function pg_is_in_backup() does not exist
LINE 1: select pg_is_in_backup();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. @Ziggy Crueltyfree Zeitgeister

Comment: Which version are you running? And how did you start the backup?

Comment: I do not see that pg_is_in_backup() exists. [It was](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-BACKUP) but not on current.